# PHP & .htaccess - turn example.com/index.php?a=6&b=3 into example.com/6/3?

Tags: url, .htaccess

How would I do this URL change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=(\d+)&b=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %1/%2
```

This will rewrite a request of `/index.php?a=6&b=3` internally to `/6/3`.

And if you rather want the other way round:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(\d+)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2
```

This will rewrite a request of `/6/3` internally to `/index.php?a=6&b=3`.

Comment: Note that you need to have `mod_rewrite` enabled on you Apache installation. It's not turned on per default, but it is a common module.

Comment: How would I make it so that it ONLY does it if I'm on index.php? Like, so it won't mess up my directories?

Comment: Which one are you using, the first or the second?

Comment: For the first, change the condition to "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^index.php\?a=(\d+)&b=(\d+)$".

Comment: For the second, you would have to change the address slightly, so instead of requesting /6/3 you would request /some_unique_name/6/3, where some_unique_name is some appropriate name that doesn't match your directories.  The condition would then be "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/some_unique_name/(\d+)/(\d+)$"