# url.com/cat/index.php?select=high2low&page=2 --> url.com/cat/high2low/2

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried rewriting dynamic url's looking like

url.com/category/index.php?select=$1&page=$2 to look like url.com/category/$1/$2.

I got the following code (changing a to select and b to page) at [PHP & .htaccess - turn site.com/index.php?a=6&b=3 into site.com/6/3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605967/php-htaccess-turn-site-com-index-phpa-6b-3-into-site-com-6-3) ... but it doesn't work for me.

The code I'm currently using is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^select=(\d+)&page=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %1/%2
```

mod_rewrite is enabled on the server.

Comment: So you have ugly url in the input and rewrite it to the pretty one?! For what reason?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to do that from the other side:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(\d+)$ index.php?select=$1&page=$2
```

Comment: @dotban: `didn't work` is not an explanation. Show what you currently have in your `.htaccess`, say how you checked that `mod_rewrite` is enabled and works and what url you requested